# Transaction required when checking for a duplicate before inserting?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Earlier I created this stored procedure:

```
            Create Procedure CreateEmployee
            (
            @Role_ID Int,
            @FirstName Varchar(50),
            @LastName Varchar(50),
            @DateOfBirth Varchar(50),
            @Active Bit
            )
            As
            Begin

            If Not Exists (Select FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth 
                From Employee Where FirstName = @FirstName
                AND LastName = @LastName
                AND DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth)

                Begin
                Insert Into Employee (Role_ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Active)
                Values (@Role_ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @Active)
                End

            Else
                Begin
                Select 'User already exists!'
                End

            End
```

This procedure is going to check that an employee doesn't already exist in the Employee table before performing the insert.

It seems bullet proof enough in that it is a single condition check done before any sort of table altering is occurring. However after doing some reading on transactions, Im wondering if I should just make all my procedures transactions for an extra layer of protection.

tl dr; Is there a time when you shouldn't use transactions?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if I should just make all my procedures transactions for
>   an extra layer of protection.

Absolutely not! If you do that you'll make your database far more likely to [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), with the related performance problems.

> Is there a time when you shouldn't use transactions?

Look at each procedure on their own and only add a transaction where absolutely necessary, ensuring the transaction block is as small as possible. Also, ensure that the table access order in each transaction is the same. These tips will help with deadlocks and performance.

In the case in question, if you're concerned about having duplicate customers, add a unique constraint - you don't need a transaction here.

By the way, FirstName, LastName, and DateOfBirth are not good for determining uniqueness in a real database of customers. For example, it's quite possible to have two John Smith's with the same date of birth.

Comment: Related to uniqueness, if an inactive employee joined again, the above SQL would not change the Active column.

Answer (score 0):

Databases, like multi-threaded programs, allow simultaneous access to read and modify data.

In this case you;

1. *check* that a particular row does not exist
2. *insert* the row

Although each statement is atomic, any other statement/transaction can occur in between 1 and 2, including another insert of the very same row.

So, to prevent this you must use a transaction around both statements to make it one atomic action.

Anywhere you perform check/modify sequence would need a transaction wrapper if the implications are logical corruption.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a `UNIQUE` constraint to your table (if you haven't already). Then you can just `TRY` the `INSERT` and if it's a duplicate you'll get an error which you can `CATCH`. This is usually a much simpler approach than checking for duplicates in advance and you don't have to worry about transactions or deadlocks.